# How to clean up unnecessary file inside wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo?

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I currently maintaining 7 years of Wordpress site. Disk usage are recently full, so I need to check automatic back up regularly and save those back up,  and delete it from the server.

And when I check, that wordpress-seo folder inside plugins folder (which is Yoast Seo default plugin folder) are taking too much space. All I know, it's full of that plugins file from various version. To be precise, it's inside js/dist folder of wordpress-seo plugin.

It is containing several type of minified javascript with some kind of sequence or version number at the end of each name, with a total around 250-300 MB.

Can I clean up those file? If yes, is it safe? What might be the worse case I will face if I delete all of those each type from previous version, and just keep like 3 newest version?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1):

250-300MB is really a lot and I'm not sure if that is a normal situation. I'd suggest you to check how was that site maintained and managed. Maybe the updates were not made correctly (for example plugins were not updated and only overwritten using FTP).

And back to your question... The easiest way to clean these files would be to:

1. Download original, current version from Plugin Repo: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/
2. Login to your FTP server and go to wp-content/plugins/
3. Rename wordpress-seo folder
4. Upload original folder from downloaded package
5. Remove old (renamed) folder.

Comment: Worth to try, will let you know once it's done.